# Combine query 1 and query 2 results where only one column from query 2 should come

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi have two different queries from same table with different where condition but i want to bring only 1 column on the right from query 2.

```
select a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center,
       Round(sum(case when a.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* a.base_amount else a.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_current,
       Round(sum(case when b.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* b.base_amount else b.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_Pervious
from scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl (nolock) a, scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl b
where a.company_code = 'b5'
and a.posting_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
and b.company_code = 'b5'
and b.posting_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
group by  a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center
```

the query keeps executing forever.

Comment: Please only tag the relevant database.

Comment: You're performing a Cartesian join,  there are no join conditions therefore you're joining every row in table a to every row in table b... You're going to get a lot of results!

Comment: please use ansi style joins, this style of join is deprecated decades ago

Comment: @GuidoG sqlserver

Comment: @DarshanBharadwaj . . . You should ask another question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  Your query is taking a long time because that is what you have specified -- which is probably not what you want.  However, you have not said what you actually do want.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit join instead of comma separated join

```
select a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center,
       Round(sum(case when a.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* a.base_amount else a.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_current,
       Round(sum(case when b.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* b.base_amount else b.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_Pervious
from scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl a inner join scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl b
on a.company_code = b.company_code 
where a.company_code ='b5'
and a.posting_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
group by  a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center
```

Comment: still the query keeps executing forever

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as the query in the answer, except it uses ANSI joins, how does this answer OP's questions?

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
select a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center,
       Round(sum(case when a.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* a.base_amount else a.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_current,
       Round(sum(case when b.drcr_flag = 'Cr' then -1* b.base_amount else b.base_amount end),2) ytd_base_Pervious
from scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl (nolock) a
join scmdb..fbp_posted_trn_dtl b
    on a.company_code = b.company_code
    and a.fb_id = b.fb_id
    and a.account_code = b.account_code
    and a.cost_center = b.cost_center
where a.company_code = 'b5'
    and a.posting_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31' 
    and b.posting_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
group by  a.company_code, a.fb_id, a.account_code, a.cost_center
```

Comment: Please don't just guess what output format is required.  There are an infinite number of ways of joining this table to itself, the right course of action is to ask for clarity from OP about what they actually want so you can provide a good answer.